# Converting Unicode Stream to String List in D2007

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010, delphi-2007

In a D2010 application I do

```
StringList.SaveToStream (MemStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
```

I then send this stream over the network to some client applications. This part of the code is fixed (I cannot change it):

Now I have a D2007 application that needs to receive this stream and convert it back to a string list. D2007 does not include Unicode support and the `TEncoding` class. How can I convert the stream into a string list? Something similar to

```
StringList.LoadFromStream (MemStream, TEncoding.Unicode)
```

in D2010...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Delphi 2007 you have few options:

1. Use TWideStrings.
2. Read the stream content into WideString variable and assign it value to the TStrings.Text property.

Comment: Thank you! That works fine besides the fact that I have to skip the first 2 bytes of the stream (I guess this is the encoding - can anybody confirm that?).

Comment: Besides: I was talking about option 1)

Comment: @Smasher: TStrings.SaveToStream() does indeed save a BOM at the beginning of the data if the specified TEncoding defines one.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: since you cannot change your Delphi 2010 code, I'd use the `TWideStrings` class from the `WideStrings` unit in Delphi 2007: that class supports unicode strings.

Note that when encoding in Delphi 2010, you will find a BOM ([byte order mark](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)) at the start of the stream.

<strike>I would save the stream in Delphi 2010 as UTF8 ([TEncoding.UTF8](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_TEncoding_UTF8.html)), then in Delphi 2007 use the `function UTF8Decode(const S: UTF8String): WideString;` ([docs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_UTF8Decode.html)) from the `System` unit.</strike>

--jeroen

Comment: As I said: unfortunately i cannot change the D2010 code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oops, I completely overlooked that. Sorry. Will keep the answer as strike through (it might be useful to other people that are able to change the Delphi 2010 sourcecode) and edit with additional info.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! That also answers my question about the first 2 bytes of the stream.